# How to use --properties-file flag in dataproc?

Tags: apache-spark, gcloud, spark-submit, dataproc

While doing `spark-submit`, `Gcloud` gives an option to use `--properties-file` to pass the cluster properties and spark configurations. I am not sure how to use it while running the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **.txt** file with any name. The content inside this file is line separated as shown below.

```
spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris=ip1,ip2,ip3
spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONPATH=some_path
spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=some_path
```

In your spark-submit pass this .txt file as below:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=<cluster_name> --region=<region_name> main.py --properties-file <path to .txt file>
```